# Delphi TValue.Make from RttiContext.FindType with primitive types (integer, string, boolean)

Tags: delphi

Hi guys i want make a `TValue` with `TValue.Make` from two string:

```
aNewValue := '1';        // value of TValue 
aOldType  := 'integer';  // Name of TValue.TypeInfo
```

`TValue.Make` require a `PTypeInfo`. The idea is retrive the `TypeInfo` of `aOldType` with `TRttiContext.FindType`. `TRttiContext.FindType` return a `TRttiType`. `TRttiType` has `RttiType.Handle` that return a `PTypeInfo`.

This is my code, when i call `aRttiType.Handle` an `Access violation` is raised

```
var
   aRttiContext: TRttiContext;
   aRttiType:    TRttiType;
   aOldKey, aNewValue, aOldType, aNewType: string;
   aValue: TValue;
   ATypeInfo: PTypeInfo;
begin
  aNewValue := '1';
  aOldType  := 'integer';

  aRttiContext := TRttiContext.Create;
  try
      aRttiType := aRttiContext.FindType(aOldType);
      ATypeInfo := aRttiType.Handle;

      TValue.Make(@aNewValue, ATypeInfo, aValue);

      aNewType := LowerCase(aValue.TypeInfo^.Name);

      if aNewType <> aOldType then
        raise Exception.CreateFmt('"%s" is "%s" expected "%s"', [aNewValue, aNewType, aOldType]);
  finally
    aRttiContext.Free;
  end;
```

the problem seem `aRttiContext.FindType('integer')` return nil

how cai i get the type (PTypeInfo) of primitive types (integer, string, boolean)?

this works

```
TValue.Make(@aNewValue, TypeInfo(Integer), aValue);
```

but how make dynamic, eg.:

```
TValue.Make(@aNewValue, GetTypeInfoWithMagic('Integer'), aValue);
```

Comment: You have to search for 'System.Integer' for "FindType" to find tkInteger/Integer (also evident from the parameter name: "AQualifiedName"). Watch for casing, search is not case insensitive.

Comment: And once you get past that, you will find that your code will still be incorrect, because `TValue.Make()` expects a pointer to data that matches the type described by the TypeInfo. You are passing in a pointer to a `String` where a pointer to an `Integer` is expected. `Make()` will not perform a data conversion for you, you must do that yourself beforehand (ie, with `StrToInt()`).